# DDD(debugger) graphic display format

Tags: gdb, ddd-debugger

When I give for example `graph display B[576] @576`, I can see the array values, 576 values from array B[576]. But I can't understand the display result seen below. What does the first element `0 <225x>` mean?   Does it mean 225 zero values?

[image]

Comment: Yep: https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/manual/html_mono/ddd.html#Repeated%20Values (Notice its not the letter `X` its a multiplication symbol)

Comment: Oh, thanks, maybe I should take some time to read the manual later. (make your comment an answer and I'll select it. :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its showing that the value is repeated 225 times.

> Using GDB, an array value that is repeated 10 or more times is
>   displayed only once. The value is shown with a  postfix added,
>   where n is the number of times the value is repeated. Thus, the
>   display 0x0 <30x> stands for 30 array elements, each with the value
>   0x0. This saves a lot of display space, especially with homogeneous
>   arrays. ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/manual/html_mono/ddd.html#Repeated%20Values))